# How to group an array by same value from different collections in Mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to group at an array named `location` by the same `coordinates` field from both `engagements` and `broadcastreports`. Also if one `coordinate` exist in one but not on the other, It should be included anyway.

In that array I need to include a `scans` which is the number of `engagements` related to a `campaign_ad_group` and a `impressions` field which is the sum of `broadcastreports.analytics.impressions` related also to a `campaign_ad_group`.

I have the following aggregation:

```
.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            '_id': ObjectId("60520e1d09ba3a769ab85f68"),
            }
        },
          {
                $project: {
                    '_id': 1,
                    'broadcasts_to': 1
                    }
                },
        {
       $lookup: {
           from: 'campaignadgroups',
           localField: '_id',
           foreignField: 'campaign_id',
           as:'campaign_ad_group'
           }   
       },
       {
           $unwind: '$campaign_ad_group'
        },
          {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'broadcastplans',
                    let: { 'campaign_ad_group_id': '$campaign_ad_group._id' },
                    as: 'broadcastplans',
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $eq: ['$campaign_ad_group_id','$$campaign_ad_group_id' ]
                                    }
                                } 
                            },
                            { $project: { '_id': 1 } }         
                    ]
                    }
                },
         // Above it's only the necessary data gathering to get the needed engagements and broadcastreports.


                 {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'engagements',
                        let: { 'broadcastplan_ids': '$broadcastplans._id' },
                        as: 'engagements',
                        pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $and: [
                                    { $in: ['$broadcast_plan_id', '$$broadcastplan_ids'] },
                                    { $gte: ['$reported_at', ISODate('2019-12-29T15:02:47.305Z')] },
                                    { $lte: ['$reported_at', ISODate('2021-12-29T15:02:47.305Z')] }
                                    ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $unwind: '$engagements'
                        },
                 
                 {
                     $group: {
                         '_id': {
                             'adgroup_id': '$campaign_ad_group._id',
                             'coordinates': '$engagements.location.coordinates',
                             },
                             'adgroup_name': {$first: '$campaign_ad_group.name'},
                             'scans': {$sum: 1}
                         }
                     },
                     {
                         $group: {
                             '_id': '$_id.adgroup_id',
                             'name': {$first: '$adgroup_name'},
                             'location': {
                                 $push: {
                                     'scans': '$scans',
                                     'coordinates': '$_id.coordinates'
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }
])
```

The output I get is the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fe9f89f603eaa22b3d374f5"),
    "name" : "Sick name",
    "location" : [ 
        {
            "scans" : 1.0,
            "coordinates" : [ 
                -8.63294964028813, 
                56.1520268933931
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "scans" : 1.0,
            "coordinates" : [ 
                -9.63294964028813, 
                58.1520268933931
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now it comes the part that I'm stuck at. I need to look up for the collection `broadcastreports` and group by its coordinates with the `engagements` coordinates and include a field `impressions` which is the sum of `broadcastreports.analytics.impressions`.

By removing the `group` pipeline and lookup from the `broadcastreports` it will look like so:

```
.aggregate([
  .
  . // ABOVE IS THE SAME DATA GATHERING AS BEFORE
  .
                 {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'engagements',
                        let: { 'broadcastplan_ids': '$broadcastplans._id' },
                        as: 'engagements',
                        pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $and: [
                                    { $in: ['$broadcast_plan_id', '$$broadcastplan_ids'] },
                                    { $gte: ['$reported_at', ISODate('2019-12-29T15:02:47.305Z')] },
                                    { $lte: ['$reported_at', ISODate('2021-12-29T15:02:47.305Z')] }
                                    ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                        }
                    },
                      
  
                      {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: 'broadcastreports',
                            let: { 'broadcastplan_ids': '$broadcastplans._id' },
                            as: 'broadcastreports',
                            pipeline: [
                                {
                                    $match: {
                                        $expr: {
                                             $and: [
                                    { $in: ['$broadcast_plan_id', '$$broadcastplan_ids'] },
                                    { $gte: ['$reported_at', ISODate('2019-12-29T15:02:47.305Z')] },
                                    { $lte: ['$reported_at', ISODate('2021-12-29T15:02:47.305Z')] }
                                    ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            ]
                            }
                        },
                    
])
```

This gets me all the data I need which is something like:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId("60520e1d09ba3a769ab85f68"),

 campaign_ad_group: {
                _id: ObjectId("5fc1215a039674c600c0f533"),
                name: 'Sick name'
               },

 broadcastplans: [_ids],

 engagements: [ 
   {
    _id,
    coordinates: [-9.63294964028813,58.1520268933931],
    reported_at: Date
   },
   {
   _id,
   coordinates: [-8.63294964028813,56.1520268933931],
   reported_at: Date
   }
 ],

broadcastreports: [
  {
    _id,
    coordinates: [-9.63294964028813,58.1520268933931],
    reported_at: Date,
    analytics: {
      impressions: 10
    }
  },
  {
   _id,
    coordinates: [-5.20923334343244,40.4874833434234],
    reported_at: Date,
    analytics: {
      impressions: 5
    }
  }
]
}
```

I need to group this in a way that I get the following output:

```
[
 {
  _id: campaign_ad_group._id,
  name: campaign_ad_group.name,
  location: [
   {
    scans: 1,
    impressions: 10,
    coordinates: [-9.63294964028813,58.1520268933931]
   },
  {
    scans: 0, // This coordinate does not exist on the engagements so its 0 but needs to be 
              // included anyway.
    impressions: 5,
    coordinates: [-5.20923334343244,40.4874833434234]
    },
   {
    scans: 1,
    impressions: 0, // Same here
    coordinates: [-8.63294964028813,56.1520268933931]
   },
  ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$unionWith`.
Documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/

Comment: Thanks. was able to do it with `unionWith`, I will post how I managed to do it so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make use of unionWith. I did it like so:

```
.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            '_id': ObjectId("60520e1d09ba3a769ab85f68"),
            }
        },
          {
                $project: {
                    '_id': 1,
                    'broadcasts_to': 1
                    }
                },
        {
       $lookup: {
           from: 'campaignadgroups',
           localField: '_id',
           foreignField: 'campaign_id',
           as:'campaign_ad_group'
           }   
       },
       {
           $unwind: '$campaign_ad_group'
        },
          {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'broadcastplans',
                    let: { 'campaign_ad_group_id': '$campaign_ad_group._id' },
                    as: 'broadcastplans',
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $eq: ['$campaign_ad_group_id','$$campaign_ad_group_id' ]
                                    }
                                } 
                            },
                            { $project: { '_id': 1 } }         
                    ]
                    }
                },
// Needed data gathering for the next lookups

                 {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'engagements',
                        let: { 'broadcastplan_ids': '$broadcastplans._id' },
                        as: 'locations',
                        pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $and: [
                                    { $in: ['$broadcast_plan_id', '$$broadcastplan_ids'] },
                                    { $gte: ['$reported_at', ISODate('2019-12-29T15:02:47.305Z')] },
                                    { $lte: ['$reported_at', ISODate('2021-12-29T15:02:47.305Z')] }
                                    ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                $group: {
                                    '_id': '$location.coordinates',
                                    'location': {$first:'$location'},
                                    'scans': {$sum: 1}
                                    }
                                },
                            {
                                $unionWith: {
                                    coll: 'broadcastreports',
                                    pipeline: [
                                        {
                                            $match: {
                                                $expr: {
                                                    $and: [
                                                        { $in: ['$broadcast_plan_id', '$$broadcastplan_ids'] },
                                                        { $gte: ['$reported_at', ISODate('2019-12-29T15:02:47.305Z')] },
                                                        { $lte: ['$reported_at', ISODate('2021-12-29T15:02:47.305Z')] }
                                                      ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                    ]
                                    }
                                },
                                
                                {
                                    $group: {
                                        '_id': '$location.coordinates',
                                        'impressions': {$sum: '$analytics.impressions'},
                                        'scans': {$first: '$scans'}
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $project: {
                                            '_id': 0,
                                            'coordinates': '$_id',
                                            'impressions': {$ifNull: ['$impressions', 0]},
                                            'scans': {$ifNull: ['$scans',0]}
                                            }
                                        }
                        ]
                        }
                    },
                    
                    {
                        $group: {
                            '_id': '$campaign_ad_group._id',
                            'name': {$first:'$campaign_ad_group.name'},
                            'locations': {$first: '$locations'}
                            
                            }
                        }

])
```

The output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fe9f89f603eaa22b3d374f5"),
    "name" : "Sick name",
    "locations" : [ 
        {
            "coordinates" : [ 
                -9.63294964028813, 
                42.1520268933931
            ],
            "impressions" : 0,
            "scans" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "coordinates" : [ 
                -8.63294964028813, 
                41.1520268933931
            ],
            "impressions" : 0,
            "scans" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "coordinates" : [ 
                0, 
                0
            ],
            "impressions" : 1,
            "scans" : 0.0
        }
    ]
}
```